# How to run coroutine function when use sync_to_async in django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have `add_event` method that calls `_post` method as async using [sync_to_async](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/async/#sync-to-async) in django. but when I test the method inside of Django shell, it does not even run my async `_post` function and returns coroutine object instead.

Here is my method:

```
@classmethod
def add_event(cls, data):
    async_post_request = sync_to_async(
        cls._post, thread_sensitive=True
    )
    response = async_post_request(
        url=cls.ADD_EVENT,
        data=data,
        headers=cls.get_headers(),
        json_response=False,
    )
    return response
```

Screenshot of Django shell:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the async function returns a coroutine, you have to await it, or execute it with asyncio. Since you are calling it from a sync context, you should use the latest option:

```
import asyncio

@classmethod
def add_event(cls, data):
    async_post_request = sync_to_async(
        cls._post, thread_sensitive=True
    )
    response = asyncio.run(async_post_request(
        url=cls.ADD_EVENT,
        data=data,
        headers=cls.get_headers(),
        json_response=False,
    ))
    return response
```

Comment: my python version is 3.6.12 and doesn't have a ```run``` method. Also In django docs there is no run thing.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/async/#sync-to-async

Comment: `asyncio.run` is discouraged in Django as it's not threadsafe for IO operations. In such a case you'd want to use await `async_to_sync(func)(...)`.

Which would essentially make this double wrapped `async_to_sync(sync_to_async(func, thread_sensitive=True))(...)` which is entirely pointless. Just run `func(...)` - you'll only lose efficiency by double wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off rewriting your IO `_get` function to be natively async. Use an async http library such is [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/). Then you can use `async_to_sync(cls._get)(...)` from within `add_event`. You're currently converting a sync function to async just to convert it straight back to sync, causing Django to needlessly switch in an out of async. Which costs you about 4 milliseconds for each call, and no benefit to speed up because the function will still run synchronously anyway.